# error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type

Tags: c++, pointers

This is my enum header file

```
//use like PostionType::President
enum PositionType
{ President,
VicePresident,
Secretary,
Treasurer,
Normal
};
```

And in my Ballot paper header and cpp file

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include "Candidate.h"
#include "PositionType.h" //include enum

class BallotPaper
{
 private:
     PositionType _positionbp;
     std::list<Candidate> _candidatesbp;
 public:
     BallotPaper();         

    void setPositionBP(PositionType positionbp);
    PositionType getPositionBP();

    void setCandidateBP(std::list<Candidate> candidatesbp);
    std::list<Candidate> getCandidateBP();

    Candidate getCandidate(int index);
    void ShowCandidates();   
    ~BallotPaper();
   };

#include "BallotPaper.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void BallotPaper::setPositionBP(PositionType positionbp)
{
    _positionbp = positionbp;
}
PositionType BallotPaper::getPositionBP()
 {
    return _positionbp;
  }

 void BallotPaper::setCandidateBP(std::list<Candidate> candidatesbp)
 {
     _candidatesbp = candidatesbp;
 }
std::list<Candidate> BallotPaper::getCandidateBP()
{
    return _candidatesbp;
}

void BallotPaper::ShowCandidates()
{

    for(Candidate c : _candidatesbp)
    {
        c->IncreaseVoteCount();   //ERROR!!!!
    }
}
```

and this will be my candidate header and cpp file

```
class Candidate:public Member
{
 private:
   int _votecount;
   PositionType _position;
 public:
   Candidate(std::string name, int id, std::string course, int contact,          std::string joindate, PositionType currentposition) ;
   ~Candidate();

void setVoteCount(int votecount);
int getVoteCount();

void setPosition(PositionType position);
PositionType getPosition();

void IncreaseVoteCount(); //increase _votecount
}; 

#include "Candidate.h"

Candidate::Candidate()
{
  _votecount = 0;
}

void Candidate::setVoteCount(int votecount)
{
  _votecount = votecount;
}
int Candidate::getVoteCount()
{
  return _votecount;
}

void Candidate::setPosition(PositionType position)
{
   _position = position;
}

PositionType Candidate::getPosition()
{
    return _position;
}


void Candidate::IncreaseVoteCount()
{
   _votecount++;
}
```

I know is a super long code, and I appreciate for your patience in looking through it. My error  is that it seems that it cannot recognize the function of "IncreaseVoteCount" in 'Candidate c'.

I have try to double check the syntax and the code for multiple times but i still don't understand what is the error here.

Comment: Since `c` is `Candidate`, not `list<Candidate>::iterator`, you don't need to dereference it. Also, you might need to use references `Candidate& c if you're trying to modify data members.

Comment: @WilliamLee Hi thanks for replying, but what do you mean dont need to derefence it? how can i call the function from class Candidate? Forgive me if the question sounds amateur as I just start learning cpp

Comment: @hopeestheim WilliamLee meant changing `c->IncreaseVoteCount();` to `c.IncreaseVoteCount();`.

Comment: @songyuanyao HI ,thanks it does not have error! but why i do need to dereference it , if so then why some time i will need to derefence it(example, if i want to get another class private fields)

Comment: @hopeestheim See more about [Range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Comment: @hopeestheim cppreference can be a bit dense at times, but basically, 
`for (Candidate c : _candidatesbp)` means that every `c` is a _local copy_, and that changes made to `c` will not be seen elsewhere. With `for (Candidate& c : _candidatesbp)`, you have a _reference_, not a copy, to each candidate, and changes will be visible elsewhere. If you only want to read data, consider reference-to-const: `for (const Candidate& c : _candidatesbp)`

Comment: @alter igel, yes i found cpp to be much complicated as i transition from c# to cpp , thanks!